# Remove value attribute from input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one **input** field having no **value** field ( that will be added later using jQuery )

```
<input type=hidden>
```

Once I execute some function to add value to the input field I get

```
<input type=hidden value="123">
```

I want remove that value field from input field later. How can I do that?

Presently I am using the following jQuery function:

```
$('input').val('');
```

and using that I get

```
<input type=hidden value>
```

But I want

```
<input type=hidden>
```

How Can I achive that?

Thanks...

Comment: I'd be curious to know why the attribute needs to be removed.

Comment: ...and if you're starting off with no attribute, setting the `.value` property doesn't automatically create an attribute, except perhaps in older IE.

Comment: @cookie as am I .Won't it be better to just do a $('input').val('') ? To each their own :p

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @cookiemonster I get stray value otherwise and it is blocking one of my jQuery function.

Comment: Now I'm almost positive it's an XY Problem. Why not ask about the actual problem instead of your presumed solution?

Comment: My I know why am i getting so many downvotes for this questions?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel just set the value to null and check for if not empty in your function before proceeding, won't that be a more sensible thing to do ?

Comment: @cookiemonster Its not my presumed solution.. I have tested it with and without that stray value field

Comment: @RohanReddy.. will try that too..

Comment: Sure it is. Whatever the actual problem is, you've presumed that this is the best solution, and so that's what you're asking about. Again, if there's no attribute to begin with, then setting its `.value` property isn't going to give it an attribute. So there's something strange going on here.

Comment: @cookiemonster "if there's no attribute to begin with, then setting its .value property isn't going to give it an attribute", yes it will even if there is no value attribute and we execute $('input').val('3'), it will automatically give value attribute

Comment: @AbhishekGoel: No it does not. That sets its property, not its attribute, again except perhaps in old IE.

Comment: @AbhishekGoel check it: http://jsfiddle.net/C2bDs/

Comment: @AbhishekGoel: Well, you're doing something very wrong somewhere, but you seem content with that, so who cares I guess.

Comment: @cookiemonster.. please check ( http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_val_set) btw I am using chrome 30

Comment: @cookiemonster you may also check the fiddle by A. Wolf

Comment: AbhishekGoel: http://jsfiddle.net/5KWL6/ You are probably relying on the HTML view in the console, right? Otherwise how are you determining that there's an attribute? And how does @A.Wolff's demo prove your point?

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, i am checking the html view in the console. Could you please tell me why isn't that right?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel my jsfiddle was to prove than no attribute value is added, i tested in chrome 30 too. Where do you see any attribute being added?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel  I'd take the console view with a grain of salt, but in all demos shown here, the element has no attribute, so I really don't know the point you're trying to make. If you're getting an attribute, you're doing something wrong somewhere. If the presence of an attribute is breaking your code, then again, you're doing something wrong, unless it involves a DOM query by attribute, like `$("input[value]")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery's [`removeAttr` removes attributes](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).
Try: `$("input").removeAttr( "value" );`

#### Edit 2018-09-11:

Since jQuery isn't necessary to do this, and the title doesn't specifically ask about jQuery (although the tags do), here's the solution in plain JavaScript:

```
document
    .querySelectorAll( "input" )
    .forEach( ( input ) => {
        input.value = "";
        input.removeAttribute( "value" );
    } );
```

However, as @cookie-monster originally said: you probably shouldn't be removing DOM attributes. Consider rethinking your application.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for somehing like:

```
 $('input').removeAttr('value');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('input').removeAttr('value');
```

Answer (score 2):

use `removeAttr()`

```
$('input').removeAttr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .removeAttr() method. This  method uses the JavaScript removeAttribute() function, but it has the advantage of being able to be called directly on a jQuery object and it accounts for different attribute naming across browsers.

```
$('input').removeAttr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove 'value' attribute from all inputs you can use

```
$('input').removeAttr('value');
```

You can also use input ID.

**Example:**

```
$('#Input_Id').removeAttr('value');
```

Or class for remove attribue

**Example:**

```
$('.Input_Class_Name').removeAttr('value');
```